# Green's Theorem for a line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I have been trying to evaluate this closed-path line integral and i have not had any luck.
$\int_c-y^2dx+5dy$

where C is the cardioid $2(1-cos\theta)$ oriented counterclockwise

i have read that it may be easier in polar coordinates. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, use Green's Theorem and convert the resulting double integral to polar coordinates.

Comment: Your Cardioid is given in polar coordinates. How were you attempting to do this *without polar coordinates*? You can only express $\theta$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ piecemeal, with two different pieces to get the whole circle, and clearly that is a nasty relationship. On the other hand, it is easy to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\theta$ and the calculation is straight-forward. Break yourself of the bad habit of just automatically working in cartesian coordinates. Let the problem show you what to use. This one is screaming "polar" at the top of its lungs.